# How can I reduce .NET build times in Cloud Build

Tags: .net, testing, dockerfile, .net-6.0, google-cloud-build

### Background

I have a CI/CD pipeline for my .NET applications using Google Cloud Build that builds my project and runs some tests before outputting and deploying an image to Cloud Run. I am experiencing long build times and wanted to know if there are recommendations to reduce build times. My pipeline consists of three steps, namely:

- start database containers,
- mirror sub-module projects, and finally
- build the project and run tests.

### Problem

My pipeline takes 7m30s+ to complete which is quite long for a small application. Of the three steps listed, the build and test step takes the longest with 5m+ to execute and I want to reduce this time.

### What I have tried:

Below are some of the ways I tried improving the execution times of the pipeline using the Dockerfile.

##### Optimised image usage

I have switched out the bulky base images retrieved from MCR to slim versions.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim AS environment
```

##### Reduced referenced projects

I reduced the projects included in the solution and project files to the bare minimum required and only make them available during the pipeline.

##### Build first

Building the projects as an explicit first step and using the output in the test step with `no-build` arguments

```
RUN dotnet build -c Release
ENTRYPOINT dotnet test -c Release --no-build
```

##### Direct testing

Directly calling the `test` option as it includes `restore` and `build` by default.

```
ENTRYPOINT dotnet test -c Release
```

### Additional information

- I am using the base Cloud Build machine type which has 1 vCPU and 4GB RAM.
- For the majority of the time, my builds stay within the 120 free build minutes per day and I would like to keep my costs as low as possible.
- Locally I can execute the same steps as the pipeline in about 1m37s, however, my device specs are significantly higher than the Cloud Build machine specs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [cached Docker image](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/speeding-up-builds#using_a_cached_docker_image) to speed up your Cloud Build builds.

> The easiest way to increase the speed of your Docker image build is by specifying a cached image that can be used for subsequent builds. You can specify the cached image by adding the --cache-from argument in your build config file, which will instruct Docker to build using that image as a cache source.

Additional best practices and guidelines on how you can speed up builds are also mentioned in this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/speeding-up-builds).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I updated my builds to use a cached Docker image. When changes were made that did not affect the project itself, the cached docker image immensely reduced the build times. However, whenever code changes are made, the application is still rebuilt and the cached Docker images make no difference in the build times. I am currently implementing the other changes in the guide linked and will update you when I get new results.